# Getting "Can't find custom atter constructor image" from a .dll after upgrading to Unity5

Tags: dll, unity-game-engine

I've just upgraded to Unity5 and a small .dll I've made started to give the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)

at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Missing method .ctor in assembly [myproj... .dll], type System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute
The class System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute could not be loaded, used in Logger
Can't find custom attr constructor image: [myproj... .dll]
mtoken: 0x0a00000e
​
```

The .dll worked perfectly before updating to Unity 5, and I did recompile the .dll with the unity5 version UnityEngine.dll (needed by my library), but that didn't help. Any ideas how to fix this?